# Whats the basic reason behind placement of these deities?

Tags: gods, temple

What is the basic reason behind placement of deities in the three layers in the Dakshineswar Adyapith temple?

Please cite proper source.

[image]

Comment: What is the guaranty that they have followed a certain philosophy in those arrangements?

Comment: For example the Guru resides in Sahsradala lotus, which is above the head but the Ishta resides in the heart .. So, if that philosophy is followed Sri Ramakrishna shd be at the top?

Comment: @Rickross Guru in the sahasrara is explained by some by the fact that the relationship with him is based upon intelllect and with Ishta upon emotion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Garva-griha of the Adyapith temple has three altars, one atop the other, are like stairsteps.

On the bottom altar is a murthi of Sri Ramakrishna, with the word "Guru" inscribed nearby.

On the middle altar is a replica of the murthi of Adya Ma found by Annada Thakur in the Eden Garden. This murthi is made of eight metals. Nearby is inscribed "Jnana and Karma."

The topmost altar is adorned by the murthis of Radha and Krishna, known all over India as the Divine Couple. They are encircled by the sacred syllable om, and at their feet is inscribed the word "Prema." Thus love is the foremost virtue and the clearest path to God.

So one has to get guidance from Guru first, and proceed on the spiritual path by nishkama karma ( Upasana and service to all beings) and studying the scriptures maintaining austerity. On this path, the grace of Mahamaya is crucial, as She is tye one Who binds or liberates us.

Finally one can reach the pinaccle which is Pure and Selfless Love. This Love is the 'panchanma purushartha' itself and this takes tye aspirant to God. God is Pranava (Om itekaksharam Brahman--Gita) Who is both Purusha (Sri Krishna) and Prakriti (Sri Radhika).

Reference:  https://www.adyapeath.org and Swapna-Jivan by Annada Thakur.